# Business rules in Django models and admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have tried to find similar examples from Django tutorials/documentation but haven't found anything so far.
Business rules I would like to have is:

- Each **Sample** has its own set of **Batch**'es
- **Session** has set of **Sample**s and each sample can have only one batch in **Session**

*Example Samples:*

WineA (batch: 2016, 2017, 2018)

WineB (batch: 2015, 2019)

*Example Session:*

Session1

WineA - batch 2017

WineA - batch 2018

WineB - batch 2015

The models look like this:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sample_name

class Batch(models.Model):
    batch_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    batch_sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.batch_name

class Session(models.Model):
    survey_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    survey_sample = models.ManyToManyField(Sample)
```

But what I can't wrap my head around is whether I should define these business rules in the models or should views take care for that.

The expected result would be that when I add a new Session in Django site admin, I can add Sample's (more than once to same session) and select or define a batch for each sample.

Comment: For many Django applications, I would choose whatever is simpler. My guess is putting the constraints in the models.

Comment: The models that you have created seem to already have accomplished your intended result... what is missing? EDIT: nvm, I see the business rule above, okay

Answer (score 0):

I think that it may be useful for you do this in a slightly different way. I'm not sure exactly what you're going for but I'm guessing this is for scheduling wine tastings. Maybe some layout like this:

```
class Wine(models.Model):
    wine_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.wine_name

class WineVintage(models.Model):
    wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.year) + ' ' + str(self.wine)

class Session(models.Model):
    survey_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    survey_sample = models.ManyToManyField(WineVintage)
```

In this case, you can have your wines (ie: `Wine: Caymus`) and then you have your vintages (ie: `WineVintages: 2017 Caymus, 2016 Caymus`) and then in your session you have `WineVintages` which will make sure that you do not repeat the same type and year.

Does this help? If not, please let me know and I'll try to suggest something else. Also please note that I hand wrote this and there may be syntax error or typos.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It sort of solves one half of the problem but not quite. For example, current setup would not allow me to add one wine/batch combination to the same session twice (or any number of times) (imagine blind tasting) or control the wine list order. For the latter I think I have to use "through" model but I'm not sure yet if that would be the best way to go. It also would mean that I would need to create custom admin views.